# How to prevent auto download of doc/docx/pdf file on iframe src

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, simple-html-dom

I want to build a blurred preview of the document. The document is uploaded to the same domain. The document can be **doc/docx/pdf**. I tried so many workarounds with `iframe`, `embed`, `object`.

`<iframe src="URL" title="Embedded Document" style="width:100%; height:500px; border: none;"></iframe>`

`<iframe src="URL#toolbar=0" title="Embedded Document" style="width:100%; height:500px; border: none;"></iframe>`

`<embed src="URL">`

`<object data="URL"></object>`

But nothing achieve my requirement.

**TASK:**
I want to show a preview of the document on the web page which can not be downloadable. Above workarounds, auto-downloads the doc/docx file when I refresh the web page. I want a blurred preview of the document like here: https://essaybatch.com/how-would-you-convene-and-run-your-meetings-if-you-are-based-in-the-united-states/  and the file shouldn't be auto-downloaded.

This requirement is strongly stated by the client, so I can't avoid the feature. You're able to use HTML,CSS,JS,PHP.

Comment: Why would you use a blurred preview of the real document? Just show it for logged in users (customers) after they bought it. If its blurred like in your example I cant really tell if it its the real document or not which is also not important I guess

Comment: @Aaron
The blur effect can be achieved by CSS. I mentioned about the security issue to the client and he was about to cancel the order. He needs the preview of the document like in the provided URL. So I got no option here. Please help me

Comment: Just use a static image I dont really get why the real document has to be blurred, seems like a security / business risk to me.

Comment: just add the type:image/png' for images and so on for other docs  to the API from where you are storing or retrieving it

Comment: @Aaron ik, but client keep asking for that

Comment: @AdeshKumar no brother, the client really needs the preview of the actual document

Comment: My approach would then be to blurr the image in my backend with php (should be a library for that) and afterwards pass it to the frontend just as plain picture so the customer can only download / save the picture nothing else. Is that a possible approach?

Comment: Why does it need to be the actual document if it's blurred?

Comment: The client is not always right sometimes. It took me about 15 seconds to [download the example](https://essaybatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/order_65973_1.docx) you mentioned, so you would do well to mention that to your client.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would implement it:

1. Use a PHP library to take a screenshot of the document and save it as an image.
   In the iframe source, you should include that image and blur it using CSS. Do not include the link to the actual `.doc` file because it is a security risk.
2. Add JS listener to page for a cookie that contains a secret value. When cookie is set to that value, page reloads and changes the iframe source to the file location for download.
3. After payment is completed, return a callback with the secret value (token) that sets the cookie via PHP.